Can a functor $F$ between distinct categories be both left and right adjoint to the same functor G?
I know that there are endofunctors that are self-adjoint.  Here, I am not interested in this case.
So, suppose that $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ are "distinct" categories, and $F:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$ a functor.  Could there exist a functor $G:\mathcal{D}\to\mathcal{C}$, that is both a right- and left- adjoint of $F$?
I put scare quotes around "distinct" above because there's the possibility of isomorphism between $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$.  Since endofunctors can be self-adjoint, I suspect that the answer to this question will depend on whether the "distinct" qualification really means "non-isomorphic".  Please consider this aspect in your answer.
NB: my question is different from this earlier question because in mine only two functors are involved.

Look up dagger-categories.

Yes: these are sometimes called Frobenius pairs.
